# Create plane by dragging in viewport

Tags: modeling

Is there a way to create a plane by click dragging in the view port? I'm trying to defining the plane using 2 corners interactively.

Comment: Not natively no, as far as I know. Maybe this helps https://www.blendermarket.com/products/snap-utilities (commercial addon)

Comment: link has expired

Answer (score -3):

So, are you wanting to draw a diagonal line and it generate a rectangle? You'll have to write a script for that by using the Pythagorean theorem. But you can't determine a rectangle knowing it's diagonal length only. You must also know the width to length ratio because one diagonal length can have infinite variations of a rectangle. So, unless you want a hard coded width to length ratio, every time you draw your line you'll have to employ the extra step of determining the ratio by determining the slope of the line on an XY coordinate.

Example:

(X,Y)+(X౽,Y౽)= diagonal line

(X౽,Y౽-Y) = Other X vertex

(X౽-X,Y౽)= Other Y vertex

(X,Y)+(X౽,Y౽)+(X౽,Y౽-Y)+(X౽-X,Y౽)= rectangle

Comment: Could you give more concrete indications? This is of no help regarding the question.

Comment: First of all, his question was simply asking if you can make a plane by drawing a line. I answered it by stating he needs to write a script for that. If​ anything his question is a candidate for deletion for being vague and yet I went above and beyond to show him the math behind solving the problem. Should I develop the script for him too? You​ are not using the down vote as intended.

Comment: @LetTheWritersWrite to be clear I DVed your answer, because it is plane wrong. You are not thinking of it the same way the OP is. Look at how [sketchup](https://youtu.be/t5gj8a2yRBE?t=55) does it as an example.

Comment: @David "plane" wrong? Intended pun? ;-)

Comment: "plane" wrong you guys kill me...
sorry for the unclear wording, but yes the sketchup / Modo way of dragging out a plane is what I am looking for.