# Create a cube similar in 3D Studio Max

Tags: modeling

I would like to know if there is a way (native or addon) to create a cube exactly like you can in 3D Studio Max?
What I mean by that is click once to define one of the corners, then again to declare a rectangle, and then once more to bevel it. I believe it's a really useful feature and I would be glad to see in Blender.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/78250/26640

Comment: For what? To get the same feeling like in max? It's definitely possible implementing that using python. However, it's just a stupid cube. Tell me me one good reason, why that's an awesome feature and I'll build that for you.

Comment: @brockmann Because for new users especially it's faster than Blender's way of creating the same shape. Remember that this feature can do more than just cubes, any cuboid is possible with this tool. Does that mean you have to make this now or do I not count?

Comment: possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50530/precise-box-creation-migrating-from-3d-max

Comment: If you don't count, Brenticus, I'll copy-paste your comment gladly. :D
brockmann, there are a lot of possible scenarios, where it would be more efficent, than SHIFT + A, move in position, edit mode, align the faces. When I'm modeling, I often start out from your "stupid cube", I often add loops to it, and modify that one little cube. Don't underestimate it. ^^
Now I need my script. :D
As a programmer, I know it right, that I could implement that via script, but I wanted to know first if it isn't a feature already..

Comment: Speed? I bet I'm faster using blender @Brenticus

Comment: For the same operation in both programs 3DS Max takes less clicks and keystrokes, so.... I'm skeptical :)

Comment: Being skeptical is a good thing :) Just give me some values, time measurements and any real world example @Brenticus Also I'm curious how long it takes starting max in its newest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question, there is no way (native or addon) to have this exact tool in Blender. It could definitely be implemented with Python but as of this answer I have not seen it done.

**EDIT:** Just saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wVcmThh09o) about upcoming features in Blender 2.8 and the tool you are looking for is actually included in the current builds of Blender 2.8. THe most up to date build for 2.8 can be found [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/). Just remember this is still very incomplete, and also not very stable.

Comment: I'm going to get my feet wet with the libraries Blender offers, and do it myself then. :D I'll post it somewhere if it's done.

Comment: @OfficialSwyse Take a look at the edit to my answer, I think you'll like what you see...